# Proving an equality for $\int_{0}^{1}x^{4}f(x)\,dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, mean-value-theorem

Let $f : [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$, and continuous. The goal is to prove that there exists a $c$ in $[0, 1]$ such that

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{4}f(x)\, dx = \dfrac{1}{5}f(c)$$

So far however, what I have is this. By MVT we have that $ \int_{0}^{1}x^{4}f(x)\,dx = (1 - 0) \cdot c^{4}f(c)$ for $c$ in $(0, 1)$, which is strictly less than $ f(c)$ for some $c$ in $[0, 1]$. This is just an inequality however and not the equality wanted, which is stronger. Are there any good hints for getting an actual equality?

Edit: as commenters here pointed out, this directly follows from a more general version of the mean value theorem. But I am also interested in more elementary ways to prove it, possibly using other techniques like the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: Use the “general form” of the [mean value theorem for integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorems_for_definite_integrals) ...

Comment: Look at the question [A consequence of the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630357/a-consequence-of-the-mean-value-theorem-for-integrals), and follow the procedure given there, with the function $g(x) = x^4$. Note that $\int_0^1 g(x)dx = \frac 15$, so it's precisely the statement you need.

Comment: Thank you, it seems like this is just a direct consequence of the general theorem. Although I am also interested in other proofs, e.g. apparently there is an answer below that defines a function $g(x)$ as the integral over two variables, and proves that $g(c) = 0$.

Comment: I see what you mean. In that case, the answer below uses the fact that $y^4 \geq 0$ on $[0,1]$, so it is definitely a different proof.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $f(x)\not\equiv 0$. Consider $g(x)=\int_0^1 y^4\left[f(y)-f(x)\right]dy$. Since $\{f(x):x\in[0,1]\}$ is compact, its maximum and minimum are attained at two (not necessarily unique) points $x_\text{max}$ and $x_\text{min}$, respectively. The function $g(x)$ is continuous and we have
$$
{
g(x_\text{min})<0\quad,\quad g(x_\text{max})>0.
}
$$Therefore, there exists a $c\in [x_\text{min},x_\text{max}]$ such that $g(c)=0$. This proves what we wanted.